# Log out from facebook

Tags: facebook, apache-flex, logout

Well i developing a Flex desktop app and i cant logout form facebook. I mean after loggin in and updating the photo i want to update, i run the method to log out, which looks like this

```
FacebookDesktop.logout(handleLogout);
```

Where handleLogout is a function where i can do other things.

The method runs but never log out. I think that maybe loading an other request i could log out, and i find that using:

> "https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?" + info.get_accessToken() +
>   "&next=http://www.Google.com"

would log out, but i dont know where i ca get the accesToken.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I finnaly got the method to get the access token, usig https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials but i dont knwo how to get it from flex and i dont really sure if using this url i could log out from facebook...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is implemented in for asp.net page using C# code.

**EXPLANATION**

First you need to send a request to authenticate the user(the IF part). You will get a "CODE" on successfull authentication. Then send a request with this code to authorize the application. On successful authorization you will get the access token as response.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["code"] != null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=CURRENT_URL&client_secret=APP_SECRET&code="+Request.QueryString["code"]);
     }
     else
     {
        Response.Redirect("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=CURRENT_URL&scope=read_stream");
     }
}
```

**HERE IS THE PROCEDURE**

1. Create an asp.net website
2. In the **default.aspx** page implement the above code.
3. Replace **CLIENT_ID,APP_SECRET** with the **AppId** and **AppSecret** respectively
4. **CURRENT_URL** should be the url of the page in which you are implementing the code.
5. The part "**&scope=read_stream**" is not mandatory. If you need any additional permissions please enter it here as comma separated values.

You will get a string in the format

**access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_VALUE&expires=EXPIRY_TIME**

as response.

---

Try this to send a POST request using flex

```
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=YOUR_URL&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN");
request.data = binaryData;
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST
urlLoader.load(request);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i already develop the Facebook aplication, following the steps i rewrite some code... but i cant get the access token... would you know how i could get it?

Comment: Thanks Robin,unfortunatelly i dont really undertand the procedure you posted, i mean, i dont know much about html. Maybe there is a easiest way to get the acces token...

Comment: Do you have basic working knowledge in asp.net or C#.net. plz let me know. This is the standard graph api procedure to  retrieve an access token. The only other way in which you can get an access token is by visiting (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET). There is a button "GET ACCESS TOKEN". But this is the access token for you only. You can't get access tokens for other users in this manner

Comment: Thanks Robin, i finnaly use another method to get the access token usign https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=THE_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=THE_CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials but i cant log out with the access token, so the question know is if there is a correct method to log the user out of facebook. Thanks you so much for your time and help

Comment: Send a POST request to 'https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=YOUR_URL&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN'  This is the proper method to logout of Facebook as mentioned in Facebook site (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ Read topic Logout)

Comment: The access token you got is not a User access token. but it is an App Access token. Both are different. You should use User access token to logout, not the App access token

Comment: I finnaly get the user access token, moddifing a bit the facebook api, but i still dont know the correct method to log the user out... do you know some??? Thanks you so much Robin

Comment: Hi Matias, I haven't used flex yet. But i just did a bit of research and edited my answer. Just try it. Not sure whether it will work or not though

Comment: Find the section "Try this to send a POST request using flex"

Comment: Thanks robin for all your help!!! You give me interesting ideas, know me problem is to delete the cookies from flex: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7853761/977081 Thanks you!!!